# How does the standard C preprocessor interpret "0xFFFFFFFF"?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How does the standard C preprocessor interpret "0xFFFFFFFF": 4G-1 or -1?

Same question for "~0"...

If the answer is -1, then how do I make it interpret it as 4G-1 (i.e., is there any other way besides explicitly using 4294967295)?

P.S.: I tried it on MS Visual Studio (using a comparison rather than calling 'printf' of course, as the latter would simply print according to the specified '%'), and the answer was 4G-1. But I'm not sure that MS Visual Studio uses a standard C preprocessor.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what `4G-1` is supposed to be?

Comment: you are assuming there is a difference in the bit patterns and the compiler has not properly placed the bit pattern in the variable?

Comment: the answer is there is no difference, it has nothing to do with the compiler and everything to do with the programmer.  if you tell the compiler, through your code, to interpret the bit pattern as a signed value then you get -1, if you tell the comiler, through your code, to interpret that same variable/bit pattern as unsigned then you get the unsigned value 2^32 - 1.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the preprocessor is concerned, `0xFFFFFFFF` is just a hexadecimal constant. Numbers in preprocessor expressions (which are relevant only in `#if` and `#elif` directives) are taken to be of the widest available integer type; the preprocessor will treat `0xFFFFFFFF` as a signed integer constant with the value 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or `4294967295` (since, as of C99, there is always an integer type of at least 64 bits).

If it appears anywhere other than a `#if` or `#elif` directive, then the preprocessor is irrelevant.  A hexadecimal constant's type is the first of:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `long int`
- `unsigned long int`
- `long long int`
- `unsigned long long int`

For this particular constant, there are several possibilities:

- If `int` is narrower than 32 bits and `long` is wider than 32 bits, then the type is `long`;
- If `int` is narrower than 32 bits and `long` is exactly 32 bits, then the type is `unsigned long`;
- If `int` is 32 bits, then the type is `unsigned int`;
- If `int` is wider than 32 bits, then the type is `int`.

On modern systems, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are the most likely possibilities.

In *all* cases, the value of `0xFFFFFFFF` is exactly 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or `4294967295`; it *never* has a negative value.

However, you can easily get a negative value (say, `-1`) by *converting* (either explicitly or implicitly) the value of `0xFFFFFFFF` to a signed type:

```
int n = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

But this is not portable. If `int` is wider than 32 bits, the stored value will be 2<sup>32</sup>-1. And even if `int` is exactly 32 bits, the result of converting an unsigned value to a signed type is implementation-defined; `-1` is a common result, but it's not guaranteed.

As for `~0`, that's an `int` expression whose value has all its bits set to 1 -- which is *usually* `-1`, but that's not guaranteed.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am not using it within an "#if" or an "#elif" directive, but in a "#define" directive. Does this mean it's not a preprocessor issue but a compiler issue? Doesn't the preprocessor replace all macro definitions within the code, and then computes their final value whenever possible (i.e., whenever it's a constant value)? I would like to make sure that my preprocessor definition (a computation on 0xFFFFFFFF) is not converted by the preprocessor or compiled by the compiler as a signed value, because I am comparing it with a large unsigned integer. Thank you.

Comment: @barakmanos: Please update your question to show us the actual code in which your using `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @barakmanos: Please include both the `#define` and the code that uses it. If you can show us a small self-contained program (see http://sscce.org/), that would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.10.1 4, integer expressions evaluated in the preprocessor use the widest types in the implementation (`intmax_t` and `uintmax_t`). `0xFFFFFFFF` will have the value 2<sup>32</sup>-1 since each C implementation must support that value as an `unsigned long`. `~0` will not have that value in any normal C implementation.

Expressions are evaluated in The preprocessor only for `#if` and `#elif` statements. Text in your question suggests you are trying to print some expression resulting from preprocessor evaluation. That will not happen. Constant expressions in the source text outside of `#if` and `#elif` statements are evaluated by the regular C rules, not by the preprocessor.

Comment: The '4G-1' is meant to be '4 * (1024) ^ 3 - 1' or '4 gigabytes minus 1', equivalent to 2 ^ 32 - 1, or the UINT32_MAX.  It is not a standard notation, but it is reasonably unambiguous in context.

Comment: I'm not trying to print it (that would simply yield a positive number when using "%u" and a negative number when using "%d"). My goal is to have a constant value within my code (I don't care if it's computed by the preprocessor or by the compiler), and compare it with an unsigned integer variable during runtime. So I would like to ensure that I am not comparing the unsigned integer variable with a negative value.

Comment: @barakmanos: Unfortunately, your question is written incorrectly. I suggest you vote to close or delete it and start again. The question you want to ask is something like “How can I portably tested whether an `unsigned int` has the value 4,294,967,295?” I expect you can simply use `x == 0xFFFFFFFF`. The constant `0xFFFFFFFF` will either be used as its natural type in your C implementation (if the `unsigned int x` is the same width or shorter) or will be converted to a wider type (if `unsigned int` is wider). In neither case will its value be changed, so the comparison will work.

Answer (score 1):

ANSI C makes very few guarantees about the size of various core data types, so relying on `cpp` to interpret the value above one way or another *portably* is a mistake. If pressed, consider wrapping it in checks:

```
#if 0xFFFFFFFF == -1
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Comment: That test will not indicate that `0xFFFFFFFF` has been interpreted as -1. In a C implementation, it will be true only if the maximum integer width is 32 bits. In that case, `0xFFFFFFFF` has the value 4294967295, as desired, but `-1` is converted to unsigned, producing a true result. That is undesired, since `0xFFFFFFFF` has the desired value.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yet another testament to the tricky nature of these conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor does not interpret numbers until it is forced to.  Writing

```
 #define N  0xffffffff
```

is simple text substitution wherever `N` is used, except for preprocessor `#if` evaluation.  What C does with the value is far more likely to be what you want to ask.  For example,

```
 long number = N;  // declare and initialize to symbolic value N
```

This may or may not cause a compilation warning, or maybe an error depending on the size of a `long` and how flexibly the compiler converts initialization constants.

Comment: So????? That's why the question referred to the preprocessor, and not to the compiler. For example, what will the preprocessor do in the case of #if 0xFFFFFFFF > 0?